# Can Table value parameters (TVP) be created inside and used in a single stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure that needs to accept multiple values in a stored procedure. After looking for ways to do this it looks like Table Value Parameters (TVP) are recommended in SQL Server 2008+. I am using SQL Server 2014.

What I am wondering is if TVPs can be created and used in the same stored procedure, or do the TVPs need to be created outside the stored procedure that they are used in? I would like to be able to enclose everything inside a single stored procedure if possible, so I could call something like this from code.

`exec spMyProcedure "bob, Sam, Phil, Carol"`

Ideally I would like to deploy the script via Code First in the entity framework seeding.

Comment: You need to create TVP's outside and use it to pass multiple values to procedure. If you create inside proc then you are loosing the goal of using TVP's

Comment: there are other options besides using TVP that are less complicated if you're only trying to pass a single dimensional string array to a procedure.

Comment: @JamieD77 - What approaches have worked best for you? Do you parse apart the string within the stored procedure?

Comment: @webworm  passing in a delimited string and using a split function like one of these  http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings  or using the xml datatype

Comment: @JamieD77 - Fantastic link! Thanks. I like how it breaks down all the options you could choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Value Parameters are just Table Value Variables passed as a parameter.

So yes -- you can declare a Table Value Variable in your SP and use it in the same way you would use a Table Value Parameter.

Just like you can pass a string as a parameter or declare a string as a variable you can do the same thing with Table variables.

**HOWEVER**

Your example does not make sense.  Here you are passing a string to a stored procedure.  If that procedure is going to make that string into a table you *should* pass a TVP instead.  That is the whole point of saying they are "recommended".  What is recommended is using them instead of passing a string.

Comment: How would I go about passing a TVP via C# code? The stored procedure will be called via ADO.NET.

Comment: Fine -- here you go... first result of passing your question to google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: My question was if the Table that contained the values you wanted to pass in to the stored procedure needed to be defined already in SQL Server as opposed to dynamically. Next time try a little less attitude.

Comment: @webworm - Then I guess I don't understand your question because that does not make sense to me.  If you are passing the table as a parameter then why would it be defined somewhere else.  I don't understand.

Comment: @Hogan - Perhaps I should explain it better ... You know how the stored procedure is already written ahead of time and exists on the SQL Server? Does the Table that is being passed as a parameter to the stored procedure also have to exist ahead of time or can the Table be created inside of C# code and then passed to the stored procedure?

Comment: @webworm - it does not need to be created before-hand.  It is created on the client (C#) right before the stored procedure is called.

Comment: @webworm yes the parameter is usually defined like `@tvp as dbo.TableValueParameter` in the proc paramaters, so `dbo.TableValueParameter` has to exist in your database first.. It's a type you created like `CREATE TYPE TableValueParameter AS TABLE (id Int);`   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx